# Use complex expression with Spring EL (conditional & parenthesis)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-el

I'm using spring-EL with spring security

Is it possible to make 'complex' conditional expressions with parentesis?

```
@PreAuthorize("( hasRole('ROLE_USER') and ( isOwnerDocumentUUID( #docUuids ) ) or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')  ")
```

throw an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

> Failed to parse expression

but

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and ( isOwnerDocumentUUID( #docUuids ) ")
```

is accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have one extra `(`, the following should work:

```
@PreAuthorize("( hasRole('ROLE_USER') and isOwnerDocumentUUID( #docUuids ) ) or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')  ")
```

Comment: Thank you! I will change my glasses!